# Почему не обновляются данные?

Tags: angular4, angular5, angular

Создал сервис, который делает set при нажатии на кнопку

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor() { }

  private data;

  setData(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  getData() {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

в другом файле при нажатии на кнопку, вызывается get этого сервиса

```
this.dataService.getData()
```

но данные почему то не обновляются.... как были пустые, так и остались, при том что если вызывать из консоли, то все работает норм....
Мне нужно использовать Обсервбл? МОжно пример, как я могу использовать его в данном случае?

Comment: Покажите код, в котором вы вызываете `setData` и `getData`.

Comment: Все правильно, просто перед использованием getData(), надо использовать setData().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по поведению, Вы получаете асинхронные данные, а значит без Observable не обойтись. Вот есть русскоязычные примеры с листингами, как получать асинхронные данные: [берём данные из JSON-файла](http://dev.hive.pro/courses/angular-6/01-inicializaciya-sozdanie-servisa-css-shablon/page-3), [кэшируем ожидаемые данные, чтобы не нагружать лишний раз сервер](http://dev.hive.pro/courses/angular-6/02-routing-obmen-dannymi-mezhdu-komponentami-cherez-servis//page-2).

Answer (score 0):

Не так дружище, смотри как надо:

`my.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor() { }

    public myData: Subject<any> = new Subject();

}
```

`my.component.ts`:

```
import { DataService } from './way';

export class myComponent {
    constructor(private myService: DataService  ) {
        // Ниже подписываемся на subject из сервиса. 
        this.myService.myData.subscribe(
           (data) => {
                console.log(data);  // будет выполняться каждый раз когда будут обновляться данные в переменной myData из сервиса. 
           }
       );
    }
    // Каждый раз когда мы вызываем функцию ниже  срабатывает подписка сверху и выводит в консоль значение.
    sendData() {
        this.myService.myData.next("i send it to subscriber");
    }
}
```